# Usage of "jmdn vernachlässigen" and "jmdn ignorieren"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between *jmdn vernachlässigen* and *jmdn ignorieren*?

Comment: The former is more like "to neglect" or "to turn one's back on" while the latter is more like "to ignore."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ignorieren* is *to ignore*. You can do that at a meeting or during a term of school.

> Ich ignoriere sie.

*Vernachlässigen* is basically *to not take enough care* which for people might turn into *to not give enough attention*. It usually talks about a somewhat longer period of time (in context of people).

> Ich habe in letzter Zeit meine Freundin vernachlässigt.
>
> I haven't given my girlfriend enough attention lately.

But there is still more attention given than would be if I ignored her.